# Argument of type 'string | number | number[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number[]'?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to store typescript object with key as string and value as number | number [] | string.

```
interface Person {
  [ key : string] : number | number[] | string
}

const person:Person = {
"name" : "Harsha",
"marks" : [ 89, 90 , 100 , 67],
"class" : 8
}

function hundredsCount(marks: number[]) {
  const count:number = marks.map((each:number) => each).length
}

hundredsCount(person[marks])
```

When I call *hundredsCount* then facing an error : **Argument of type 'string | number | number[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number[]'. Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number[]'.**

Comment: the brackets are misplaced inside `hundredsCount` function

Comment: Invoke your method as follows: `hundredsCount(person.marks)` or  `hundredsCount(person["marks"])`

Comment: @uminder I tried both ways but no luck

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have declared type `Person` as very wide type which can have any string keys, with three different type of values. It means that when you access any of those properties of the value representing `Person` TS can't distinguish the type of it from what declaration says - `number | number[] | string`.

The solution is to have more strict type:

```
interface Person {
    name: string,
    marks: number[],
    'class': number,
}
```

After that `person['marks']` is inferred as `number[]`.

---

If the type cannot be so specific, lets say there are dynamic keys, but you know that such thing like `marks` key is there, then we can have such more wide type:

```
interface Person {
    [ key : string] : number | number[] | string
    marks: number[]
}
```

---

Additionally if you try to access `person[k]` where `k` is just a string value, then there need to be used typeguard in order to properly specify the type:

```
function f(k: string) {
    if (k === 'marks') {
        hundredsCount(person[k]); // inside if person[k] is known as number[]
    }
    // outside person[k] is known as number | number[] | string

}
```

Comment: thanks ,one more question while applying this logic (function k) in reducers then I am facing same error.